# Why are datatypes different in terms of bit size based on complier, and OS used

Tags: c++, programming-languages, compiler

I was reading a tutorial on C++ as I am new to programming, and I was wondering why the sizeof operator gives different output depending on what you're programming with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/1734730 read that

Comment: compilers need freedom to match your source code and the underlying CPU architecture while generating the code. Different CPU architectures work slightly different way, but your C++ source code still needs to work in all of them. Consider sizeof(T) to be documentation of how your compiler code generation handles types.

Comment: Interesting... So how much variance is there in the architecture of CPUs that are contemporary with each other in terms of release date. Is the variance in how CPUs handles variable type size proportional to how advanced the CPU is?

Comment: Contemporary is close but maybe not quite the right concept: new, low-powered embedded chips may be developed later but be weaker; "advanced" is probably closer. The types definitely do vary, see [this](http://coverclock.blogspot.com/2012/02/arduino-data-types.html) for example. I'd say it likely has to do with "advanced" usually implying greater register/pipeline bitwidth more than anything.